# Instagram sharing issue: sometimes I get the message "Unable to load image"

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram

I am using a sharing functionality to social application using `Intent`.

I have a problem with sharing an image in Instagram.

Some times I get the message

> Unable to load Image.

Here is my code:

```
String path="content://media/external/images/media/32872";

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path));
shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

How do I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
cacheDir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/LikeIT/"); 
cacheDir.mkdirs(); 
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setType("image/*");     
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filepath.getAbsolutePath())); 
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure to add permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
```

Create a file in res>xml folder as "provider_paths.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="path_name"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Create a provider tag in manifest :

```
<provider   
    android:name=".utils.FileAccessProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.path_name.file.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

This will allow access to file URIs to be posted.

```
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
        if (intent != null) {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

            File logFile = new File(path);
            if (logFile.exists()) {
                Uri logFileUri = FileAccessProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                        getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +
                                ".path_name.file.provider", logFile);
//                        shareIntent.setDataAndType(logFileUri, "image/*");
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, logFileUri);
            }

            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(shareIntent);
        } else {
            // bring user to the market to download the app.
            // or let them choose an app?
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.instagram.android"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Don't forget to add 
 `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`

Without the above permissions, there was this "unable to share" error.